# NextAuth getServerSession() does not return all the user fields in API route

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to write an API route in which I want to check if the user is authenticated and also if it is an admin. For this I try to call the getServerSession method and it does return a session but with my custom fields set to "undefined", also note that if I use the same method in getServerSideProps(ctx) it works as expected, so this only happens in an API route.

Session object in API route: DOES NOT RETURN THE EXPECTED
[Console log of the session object in api route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJUz7.png)

Session object in getServerSideProps: DOES RETURN THE EXPECTED
[Console log of the session object in getServerSideProps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kKnl.png)

[..nextauth].ts

```
import type { NextAuthOptions, Session } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import type { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

import { verifyPassword } from '@/lib/auth';
import { connectToDatabase, initUserTable } from '@/lib/db';
import User from '@/lib/dbmodels/user';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
                    throw new Error('Email-ul sau parola sunt greșite');
                }
                const db = await connectToDatabase();
                await initUserTable(db);
                const user = await User.findOne({
                    where: { email: credentials?.email },
                });
                if (!user) {
                    db.close();
                    throw new Error('Acest utilizator nu există');
                }
                const isValid = await verifyPassword(
                    credentials?.password,
                    user.password
                );
                if (!isValid) {
                    db.close();
                    throw new Error('Email-ul sau parola sunt greșite');
                }
                db.close();

                return user.dataValues;
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ user, token }) {
            const newToken = { ...token };
            if (user?.role) {
                newToken.role = user.role;
            }
            if (user?.id) {
                newToken.id = user.id;
            }
            return newToken;
        },
        async session({ session, token }: { session: Session; token: JWT }) {
            const newSession = { ...session };
            newSession.user.role = token.role as 'user' | 'admin';
            newSession.user.id = token.id as string;
            delete newSession.user.image;
            return newSession;
        },
    },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

API route

```
async function handler(req: RegisterNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not supported' });
    }

    const { name, email, password, role = 'user' } = req.body;

    const emptyData = name == null || email == null || password == null;

    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

    const user = session?.user;

    if (!user || !user?.email) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'You must be logged in.' });
    }

    if (user?.role !== 'admin') {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Only admins can create users!' });
    }

    // Rest of the code
}
```

Types file

```
import type { DefaultSession } from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
    interface Session {
        user: User & DefaultSession['user'];
    }

    interface User {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        email: string;
        role?: 'user' | 'admin';
    }
}
```

I want to be able to acces the role object also in API routes but it seems that is only accessible in the getServerSideProps() next function.

Comment: Hello, have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

Not 100% sure where the problem in your code lies, but it could be one of the following:

- creating "newSession" and "newToken" instead of just using the original ones
- type definition

I had this problem for a long time, and I just solved it today. Follow along my implementation and hopefully it will work.

## /app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
// imports (omitted)

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma) as Adapter | undefined,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                username: {
                    label: "Username",
                    type: "text",
                    placeholder: "jsmith"
                },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // user validation (omitted)

                return {
                    id: user.id,
                    email: user.email,
                    name: user.name,
                    image: user.image,
                    role: user.role
                };
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.id = user.id;
                token.role = user.role;
            }

            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            if (session.user) {
                session.user.id = token.id as string;
                session.user.role = token.role as string;
            }

            return session;
        }
    }
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Make sure that the strategy is set to jwt. I can see you have done that.

## types/next-auth.d.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
    interface Session {
        user: {
            id: string;
            email: string;
            name: string;
            image: string;
            role: string;
        };
    }
}
```

## Final Comments

Make sure to add the following to tsconfig.json

```
"include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "types/**/*.ts"],
```

Then access getServerSession normally and make sure to provide proper arguments. In my case, since I am accessing from /app router, I access the session this way:

```
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
```

Refer the documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession).

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating Next Auth with App Route, import the authOptions as shown below,

```
import {authOptions} from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
```

Further, you can define the session as follows,

```
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
```

The folder structure for the API Auth module can be defined as follows,

```
app > api > auth > [...nextauth] > route.js or route.ts
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to extends `SessionBase`

```
  interface Session extends SessionBase {
    user?: User
  }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?